# Insert data into database from TableView CheckBox JavaFX

Tags: mysql, javafx, checkbox, tableview

I have a tableView in JavaFX (for recording attendance of students) which has a column of checkBox (called "attendance") which can be checked by user. My database has a column called "classesAttended" which stores total no. of classes attended by students.

My approach is:

Database **Table name**: "student"

Database **Column Name**: "classesAttended"

TableView **Column Name:** "attendance"

---

```
    {

    TableView<Student> tables = new TableView<Student>();

    TableColumn<Student, Boolean> attendance = new TableColumn<Student,Boolean>();
    }
```

---

```
    String query="UPDATE student SET classesAttended = classesAttended+1";

    pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);

    for(TableRow tableRow: tables.getRows()){ 

        string input =    tables.get(i).getAttendanceColumn().toString();        

        if(input = "true"){

            pst.execute;

        }

    }
```

---

So I want to increment the value of "classesAttended" for student whose "attendance" column is checked. Please suggest me how can I do it.......

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your code contains some syntax errors. Why do you use the string version of the `Boolean` though? You should consider yourself lucky that `Boolean` uses literal strings for it's `toString` method and comparing therefore the result refers to the same object as `"true"`. (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) You shouldn't rely on this in general, especially if you could simply use `if (tables.get(i).getAttendanceColumn())`

Answer (score 0):

You need a `where` clause in the query to match the row on the tableView to the record in the database.